# Is the use of "for ages" correct?

Tags: present-perfect, for

> Vietnamese culture has existed **for ages**.

Is the use of "for ages" correct in this sentence? In OALD, "ages" is an informal word. If so, I think the phrase "for ages" should not be used in this sentence. Please explain it to me.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is correct. It's using the following definition of [*ages*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ages):

> **4. ages** *Informal* An extended period of time: *left ages ago.*

It is equivalent to:

> Vietnamese culture has existed for a very long time.

It doesn't say exactly how long they mean; in the context of a culture, I'd guess at least 1,000 years. In other contexts, it could mean almost any length of time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. It's used with the persent perfect to show a period of time. (Note that we don't specifically know the exact time, we are only stating how long the situation has existed up to the present.)

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are correct, but I wanted to specifically address the "formal" part.

"Vietnamese culture has existed for ages" would be fine in nearly all contexts.  It would be too informal for, say, a scholarly history of Southeastern Asia, where you would want to be more precise: "Vietnamese culture has existed for XXXX years" or perhaps "Vietnamese culture has existed since at least XXXX".